# Django adding data to models from another class

Tags: python, django, models, django-orm

I have too models `speakerCabinet` and `speakerElement`. `speakerCabinet` has many-to-many relation to `speakerElement`.

I need to do some calculations on ideal speaker cabinet size that are using some of the `speakerElement` variables. I would like to contain these calculations to separate class because they are also used without the model.

Then comes the tricky part. My view gets the `speakerCabinet` instance and generates the speaker element info with:

```
{% for cab in speakerCabinet.SpeakerElement.all %}
```

Is there any simple way add that calculation data to my speaker element model?

Comment: Can you provide some code, please?

Comment: `speakerCabinet.speakerelement_set.all` ?

Comment: Can you create method speakerCabinet.some_calculations_on_ideal_speaker_cabinet_size() and use it?